# Error while installing Alien::XGBoost library

Tags: windows, perl, xgboost, strawberry-perl

I'm unable to install the [`Alien::XGBoost`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::XGBoost) library using the default installation of Strawberry Perl on Windows 10. I'm using the 64-bit version of Strawberry Perl.

When installing `Alien::XGBoost`, I receive an error on line 49 in the `Alien/Build/CommandSequence.pm` file as shown below.

```
gmake[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/STRAWB~1/cpan/build/Alien-XGBoost-0.04-1/_alien/build_wYwS'
Alien::Build::CommandSequence> + md "C:/STRAWB~1/cpan/build/Alien-XGBoost-0.04-1/blib/lib/auto/share/dist/Alien-XGBoost/dynamic"
Alien::Build::CommandSequence> + md "C:/STRAWB~1/cpan/build/Alien-XGBoost-0.04-1/blib/lib/auto/share/dist/Alien-XGBoost/bin"
Alien::Build::CommandSequence> + copy xgboost.exe C:/STRAWB~1/cpan/build/Alien-XGBoost-0.04-1/blib/lib/auto/share/dist/Alien-XGBoost/bin/
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
external command failed at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Alien/Build/CommandSequence.pm line 49.
gmake: *** [Makefile:2881: _alien/mm/build] Error 2
  PABLROD/Alien-XGBoost-0.04.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Alien::XGBoost'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the library just confirmed it was a bug. His statement is below.  I installed the previous version and it worked perfectly.

> Thanks for reporting this!!
>   It's a bug! I forgot to quote the path.
>   As you can see both md commands have the path double quoted (""), but not the copy command.
>   I'm working to fix it and also I'm going to get travis and appveyor integrations to avoid this in the future.
>   This weekend this will be fixed. Meanwhile please install the previous version:
>   `cpanm PABLROD/Alien-XGBoost-0.03.tar.gz`